# Why is my dynamic route breaking using Hooks with route parameters?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-hooks

I've been learning React in my spare time, and in doing so I'm building a project management portal. I have a dashboard route setup at **"/"** and a projects route setup at **"/projects"**. I want to create a dynamic route for single projects, so have defined this route as **"/projects/:id"**.

The route is working when a go through the navigation like so **Home > Projects > [Single Project]**. This loads the single project component successfully.

The problem is that when I am on a single project (URL example "/projects/test-project") the main navigation breaks, and every link in the sidebar now starts with "/projects". So when in a single project, and clicking on the main navigation, the links are going to:

- /projects/dashboard
- /projects/projects
- /projects/tasks
- /projects/contacts

It's almost like when on a single page, the base URL is brought up a level; so when on a single project, all links in the sidebar are based off the relative path of "projects".

As you can probably tell, I'm finding this issue hard to explain. I've looked at various tutorials on this, and it looks like I'm doing everything correctly. Most tutorials are for React 4, so using class components - I've been through so many assumptions, so anything I can provide to further explain the issue or troubleshoot I'm happy to provide.

I am building the app using functional components and hooks, for what it's worth. In terms of my progress with React so far, this is the biggest thing that is causing me confusion, so any guidance on this would be a massive help.

**EDIT**

Here's an example of my setup, which shows the problem I'm having: https://codesandbox.io/s/funny-mendeleev-ru5vt

So everything seems to be working if I click through the main navigation. If I navigate to a single project, it breaks every other link except dashboard. Can't figure this one out.

Comment: React Router can be a pain. Consider using [Next.js](https://nextjs.org) which handles routing for you quite painlessly.

Comment: Can you please add some of your code samples?

Comment: Code example: https://codesandbox.io/s/funny-mendeleev-ru5vt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. It was something critically simple - I hadn't used forward slashes at the start of my navigation links. Router was working the way it should, but just needed to added slashes.

It really is the simplest of things sometimes. Thank to everyone who helped!

Answer (score 1):

I think your are looking for **Nested Routes**, as you are using react hooks, please change your route configs as below

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
  Link,
  useParams,
  useRouteMatch
} from "react-router-dom";
function Topic() {
  let { topicId } = useParams();
  return (
    <div>
      <h3>{topicId}</h3>
    </div>
  );
}
function Topics() {
  let { path, url } = useRouteMatch();
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Topics</h2>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <Link to={`${url}/foo`}>Foo</Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link to={`${url}/bar`}>Bar</Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link to={`${url}/baz`}>Baz</Link>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path={path}>
          <h3>Please select a topic.</h3>
        </Route>
        <Route path={`${path}/:topicId`}>
          <Topic />
        </Route>
      </Switch>
    </div>
  );
}
function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <Link to="/">Home</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/topics">Topics</Link>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <hr />
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/">
            <p>Home</p>
          </Route>
          <Route path="/topics">
            <Topics />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}
const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

UPDATE:

working demo [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/nested-routes-3o30q?file=/src/index.js)

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply! My folder structure is making this hard to implement for me. Here's an example: https://codesandbox.io/s/funny-mendeleev-ru5vt